# Compiled python program using win32com keeps crashing

Tags: python, pyinstaller, win32com

I am using pyinstaller to compile a python file to .exe. When I run the generated .exe the program crashes with this message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "EBOMcompareV3.py", line 397, in 
> File "win32com\client_*init*_.py", line 79, in GetActiveObject
> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)
> [15336] Failed to execute script EBOMcompareV3

I am attempting to connect to an open Excel workbook:

```
import win32com.client

ExcelApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelWrkbook = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook
```

Any advice?

Edit:
Here is a small program that I wrote that produces the error

```
import os, sys
import win32com.client

ExcelApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject ("Excel.Application")
ExcelWrkbook = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook

ExcelWrksht = ExcelWrkbook.Workseets(1)

ExcelWrkshet.Range("A1").value = "test"
```

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Got it.  Thank you for the link.